# how to #define c++ STL macro

Tags: c++, stl, macros

I want to use  `vector<pair<int,pair<int,int>>>` in C++, but  I want to shorten the data-type declaration to avoid re-writing the long line.
I tried to use `#define` in this way-

```
#define vector<pair<int,pair<int,int>>> my_list
```

but, on compilation it says,

> error: ‘my_list’ does not name a type

I cant find proper way to write this, please help!

Comment: Do you really want `pair<int,pair<int,int>>` over `tuple<int, int, int>` or `std::array<int, 3>` or dedicated struct ?

Comment: You could consider using `std::map`, as in `std::map<int, pair<int,int>>` or replace `pair<int,int>` with a structure.  The `typedef` is useful to create a synonym for the type.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah you are correct, `tuple<int,int,int>` will be a better option to use, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use the preprocessor for this task, you can use a type alias:

```
using my_list = vector<pair<int,pair<int,int>>>;
```

**Do not use the preprocessor for things that can be done in the language.**

---

By the way, your `#define` does not work as you've inverted the order of the arguments. The token goes first, then its desired expansion:

```
#define my_list vector<pair<int,pair<int,int>>>
```

Comment: Note that a `using` alias only works in C++11 and later. For older compilers, you can use a `typedef` instead: `typedef vector<pair<int,pair<int,int> > > my_list;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: that's entirely correct, but I think that in 2017 it should be safe to assume that "C++" = "at least C++11"...

Comment: a lot of people (myself included) still use pre-C++11 compilers. Don't assume people have access to modern compilers. Sometimes PTBs don't allow it for various reasons. Unless someone specifically asks for a solution in C++11 or later, I usually make sure to provide answers that work in older compilers, too

Comment: @VittorioRomeo thanks ! Using alias is a better way to do it!